# I want to use jquery nested sortable plugin with drag and drop in codeigniter using mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have successfully implemented it in MYSQLi, PDO and MYSQL but unable to execute or embed it in Codeigniter. Any help would be much appreciated because I am new to Codeigniter. How to convert this page in Codeigniter.

```
save.php :-

        <?php 

    require("config.php");

    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

    function parseJsonArray($jsonArray, $parentID = 0) {

      $return = array();
      foreach ($jsonArray as $subArray) {
        $returnSubSubArray = array();
        if (isset($subArray->children)) {
        $returnSubSubArray = parseJsonArray($subArray->children, $subArray->id);
        }

        $return[] = array('id' => $subArray->id, 'parentID' => $parentID);
        $return = array_merge($return, $returnSubSubArray);
      }
      return $return;
    }

    $readbleArray = parseJsonArray($data);

    $i=0;
    foreach($readbleArray as $row){
      $i++;
       $dbpo = mysqli_query($db, "update tbl_menu set parent = '".$row['parentID']."', sort = '".$i."' where id = '".$row['id']."' ");

      //$this->db->set('parent', $row['parentID'], 'sort', $i); //value that used to update column  
      //$this->db->where('id', $row['id']); //which row want to upgrade  
      //$this->db->update('tbl_menu');
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

Particularly https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

You'll want to understand the concept of Model-View-Controller to really take advantage of Codeigniter.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Thanks I have found the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
foreach ($readbleArray as $row) {
    $i++;
    $data = array(
        'parent' => $row['parentID'],
        'sort' => $i
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $row['id']); //which row want to upgrade  
    $this->db->update('tbl_menu', $data);
}
```

The rest can be easily figured out with: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Basically, make a model, add this function to the model.
Make a controller, load the newly created model and call the function.
Typically `$_POST` vars are passed to model functions rather than used directly in the model, so it might be an idea to pass the post var as a param to the function.

Comment: Thanks I have found the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I have one more question, How to retrieve session value on external file located outside the codeigniter application. Although I have seen many links on google and stack overflow but unable to get the desired result.

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new question.